# how to create multiple pages using different templates in 'gatsby-node'?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

i'm new to gatsby and trying to programatically create pages using different templates, but I'm struggling with that.

I have two different pages (landing & press), both written in mdx files, that need different routes and templates when being created programmatically.

my landing works good, but i failed to add the "press" page. everything i tried didn't work.

for information, i have a templateKey 'press' and 'landing' in each frontmatter of my markdown files.

Here is my gatsby-node file :

```
const path = require("path");
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem");
const { fmImagesToRelative } = require("gatsby-remark-relative-images");

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const landingTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/landing.js");
  // const pressTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/press.js");

  return graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(limit: 1000) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              templateKey
              locale
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach((e) => console.error(e.toString()));
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }

    const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges;

    posts.forEach((edge) => {
      const id = edge.node.id;
      createPage({
        path: edge.node.fields.slug,
        component: landingTemplate,
        context: {
          locale: edge.node.frontmatter.locale,
          id,
        },
      });
    });
  });
};

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  fmImagesToRelative(node); // convert image paths for gatsby images

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode });
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    });
  }
};
```

[here is my query in graphiQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJpri.png)

Thank you in advance for any assistance that you may be able to give me !

Comment: `posts.forEach((edge)... ` iterates over 'pages'/files ... you need a different template passed to `createPage` .. based on f.e. `slug` (like `path`) or `templateKey` (not shown in query results)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two different queries to get all your press and all landing data (filtering by each `templateKey`). Once you have the different populated objects you need to call for each object the `createPage` API to create pages and pass each template value. It should look like:

```
const path = require("path");
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem");
const { fmImagesToRelative } = require("gatsby-remark-relative-images");

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const landingTemplate = path.resolve("src/templates/landing.js");
  const pressTemplate = path.resolve("./src/templates/press.js");

  const postQuery = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 1000
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "press" }}},
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              templateKey
              locale
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach((e) => console.error(e.toString()));
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }
    

    const posts = postQuery.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges;

    posts.forEach((edge) => {
      const id = edge.node.id;
      createPage({
        path: edge.node.fields.slug,
        component: pressTemplate,
        context: {
          locale: edge.node.frontmatter.locale,
          id,
        },
      });
    });
  });

  const landingQuery = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 1000
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "landing" }}},
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              templateKey
              locale
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach((e) => console.error(e.toString()));
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }


    const landings = landingQuery.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges;

    landings.forEach((edge) => {
      const id = edge.node.id;
      createPage({
        path: edge.node.fields.slug,
        component: landingTemplate,
        context: {
          locale: edge.node.frontmatter.locale,
          id,
        },
      });
    });
  });
  
};

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  fmImagesToRelative(node); // convert image paths for gatsby images

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode });
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    });
  }
};
```

Your mistake was that you were returning your GraphQL query and that limit your capability to create new queries. Note that I've also added a promise-based approach, with an `async` and `await` functions in order to optimize the queries and the timings.

Without knowing your data structure I've duplicated the query changing the `templateKey` value, of course, you will need to customize the data that you want to gather for each template and the data you want to pass via context API.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a method based on a netlify CMS starter, which it looks like you attempted as well, that makes sure you only make the query once:

```
exports.createPages = async ({graphql,actions }) => {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query Pages {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            template
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: `${node.frontmatter.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(
        `./src/templates/${String(node.frontmatter.template)}.js`
      ),
      context: {
        slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Then in the template it self you can call this query:

```
export const aboutPageQuery = graphql`
  query AboutPage($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      frontmatter {
        title
        story {
          text
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Note: I'm still working through a method to include templates based on path. Say if you had a blog directory within pages that you wanted to apply a single template (blog-page.js) and custom path (/blog/{slug}).